# PrimeNG dropdown menu input and tooltip component in Angular 2

Tags: html, typescript, angular, primeng

I am using a dropdown directive for input in an angular 2 web application. I am trying to avoid using labels, so I want to implement the tooltip component as well. So when I hover over the dropdown item, a tooltip should pop up.

The tooltip will display, but will cause a crash and then disappear. Here is the error message:[image]

Here is my code:

```
<p-dropdown pTooltip="Who can see this file?" 
    #selectedType [options]="types" 
    (onChange)="changeAccess(file, selectedType.value)">
</p-dropdown>
```

The tooltip directive works on simple inputs, but it seems like nothing else.